# Как решить ошибку Multiple root tags?

Tags: android, android-xml

При компиляции Android Studio выдаёт ошибку `Multiple root tags`. Погуглив я так и не понял решения проблемы. Объясните пожалуйста в чём проблема. Вот сам код:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/apps_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
</ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Добавьте код вашей активности и желательно, добавьте сообщение о ошибке.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый.

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка как вы могли понять переводится как: `Несколько корневых тегов`. Это вызвано тем что у вас не совсем корректно реализован список `ListView`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/apps_list"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/apps_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

В вашем коде вы пытаетесь сделать из `apps_list` еще один корневой элемент.

Comment: не уверен на счет `ListView`, но с любым другим `View` так делать можно

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov, с любым другим да, но думаю что в данном случае ошибка вызвана именно этим элементом. Безусловно вложенные view это нормально, но не в данной ситуации :)

Comment: К сожалению ваш код тоже не работает и ошибка не исчезла.

Comment: @TwinSpirit, тогда приложите код вашей активности (например `MainActivity.java/.kt`) и будем разбираться где у вас ошибка там может быть, попробуйте еще перезагрузить студию с очисткой кэша, может поможет

Comment: @Andrew как тaк перезагрузить студию?

Comment: `Invalidate cases/restart` в пункте меню `File`